Node.JS SDK , what connection params should be used?
Can someone please verify the keys I am using for Node SDK for milvus?
const milvusClient = new MilvusClient({
   address: '<server-name>:port',
   username: 'username',
   password: 'password',
   ssl: true ,
   tls:{
    rootCertPath:'/root/milvus.crt'
   },
  });


const milvusClient = new MilvusClient({
   address: '<server-name>:port', // your milvus address
   username: 'username', // your milvus username
   password: 'password',  // your milvus password
   ssl: true , // I don't think you need it
   tls:{
    rootCertPath:'/root/milvus.crt' // path to your milvus cert file if you need to connect to the tls enabled milvus 
   },
  });


I am unfortunately not able to validate your parameters since they should be configured based on your specific environment.

Address is the milvus IP address
Username is your username used to connect to Milvus
Password is your password used to connect to Milvus
SSL is false by default; Set it to true if you are using Zilliz Cloud.
You can refer to this page for more information: https://milvus.io/api-reference/node/v2.2.x/Client/MilvusClient.md

